# output for min/max sometimes correct, other times not

Tags: python, loops, max, min

So I'm writing a basic program, and part of the output is to state the lowest and highest number that the user has entered. For some reason, the **min and max** are correct some of the time, and not others. And I can't figure out any pattern of when it's right or wrong (not necessarily when lowest number is first, or last, etc). Everything else works perfectly, and the code runs fine every time. Here is the code:

```
total = 0
count = 0
lst = []
while True:
    x = input("Enter a number: ")
    if x.lower() == "done":
        break
    if x.isalpha():
        print("invalid input")
        continue
    lst.append(x)
    total = total + int(x)
    count = count + 1
    avg = total / count

print("The total of all the numbers your entered is: " + str(total))
print("You entered " + str(count) + " numbers.")
print("The average of all your numbers is: " + str(avg))
print("The smallest number was: " + str(min(lst)))
print("The largest number was: " + str(max(lst)))
```

Any ideas? Keep in mind I'm (obviously) pretty early on in my coding study. Thanks!

Comment: You might try converting the input to an `int()` before appending it to `lst` if you want min/max to treat the values as numbers.

Comment: Can you give a few examples of your results? You say that sometimes your answers are wrong, but it is important to actually see the output before making a conclusion here

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As an aside, why not use proper string formatting?

Comment: You are taking string input – which sorts alphabetically – but expecting it to sort numerically when using `min` and `max`. @MarkMeyer was on the right track by suggesting casting to `int`. Your total and average are correct because they are calculated from numbers separate from the list of input _string_ from which you calculate max and min.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for the help! Btw, when you say "use proper string formatting"... I'm not sure what that means, but now I'm think you mean print("text", variable) rather than print("text" + variable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert your input to `int` when you are adding it to the total, but not when you are finding the `min` and `max`.

When given strings, `min` and `max` return values based on *alphabetical order*, which may sometimes happen to correspond to numerical size, but in general doesn't.

All you need to do is to append input as `int`s.

```
total = 0
count = 0
lst = []
while True:
    x = input("Enter a number: ")
    if x.lower() == "done":
        break
    if x.isalpha():
        print("invalid input")
        continue
    lst.append(int(x)) # this should fix it.
    total = total + int(x)
    count = count + 1
    avg = total / count
```

You might also want to use string formatting to print your answers:

```
print(f"The total of all the numbers your entered is: {total}")
print(f"You entered {count} numbers.")
print(f"The average of all your numbers is: {avg}")
print(f"The smallest number was: {min(lst)}")
print(f"The largest number was: {max(lst)}")
```

Comment: Fixed! Thank you! Still sorting out types and all that in my head, but this helps a lot.

Comment: Great! If that was helpful you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;)

Answer (score 1):

If, at the end of your program, you add:

```
print("Your input, sorted:", sorted(lst))
```

you should see the `lst` in the order that Python thinks is sorted.

You'll notice it won't always match what you think is sorted.

That's because you consider `lst` to be sorted when the elements are in numerical order.  However, the elements are not numbers; when you add them to `lst`, they're strings, and Python treats them as such, even when you call `min()`, `max()`, and `sorted()` on them.

The way to fix your problem is to add `int`s to the `lst` list, by changing your line from:

```
lst.append(x)
```

to:

```
lst.append(int(x))
```

Make those changes, and see if that helps.

P.S.:  Instead of calling `str()` on all those integer values in your print statements, like this:

```
print("The total of all the numbers your entered is: " + str(total))
print("You entered " + str(count) + " numbers.")
print("The average of all your numbers is: " + str(avg))
print("The smallest number was: " + str(min(lst)))
print("The largest number was: " + str(max(lst)))
```

you can take advantage of the fact that Python's `print()` function will print each argument individually (separated by a space by default).  So use this instead, which is simpler and a bit easier to read:

```
print("The total of all the numbers your entered is:", total)
print("You entered", count, "numbers.")
print("The average of all your numbers is:", avg)
print("The smallest number was:", min(lst))
print("The largest number was:", max(lst))
```

(And if you want to, you can use `f-strings`.  But you can look that up on your own.)

Comment: Fixed! Thank you! Still sorting out types and all that in my head, but this helps a lot.